# Mongoose deep populate with self-referencing children

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose

This is working code to populate my Locations collection, which can have self-referencing child Locations.  It uses [mongoose-deep-populate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-deep-populate).  But I need to add another ".childLocations" to my path variable for every extra level of depth that I want to handle.  Is there a better way to accomplish unknown depths of self-references?

I have this node.js code.

```
var path = 'childLocations.childLocations.childLocations.childLocations.childLocations.childLocations';
exports.list = function(req, res) {
  Location.find().sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').deepPopulate(path).exec(function(err, locations) {
    console.log(locations);
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      res.jsonp(locations);
    }
  });
};
```

Here is the schema:

```
var LocationSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: 'Please fill Location name',
        trim: true
    },
    projectsExecutedHere: Boolean,
    childLocations: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Location'
    }],
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
});

mongoose.model('Location', LocationSchema);

var deepPopulate = require('mongoose-deep-populate');
LocationSchema.plugin(deepPopulate);
```

### ----------

Before trying mongoose-deep-populate, I had seen that mongoose 3.6 had support for deep population, but I could only make it go one level deep.  This is what I tried:

```
Location.find().sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').populate('childLocations').exec(function (err, locations) {
        Location.populate(locations, {path: 'childLocations.childLocations'},
            function (err, data) {
                console.log(err);
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(400).send({
                        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                    });
                } else {
                    res.jsonp(locations);
                }
            }
        );
```

For the path I also tried 'childLocations.childLocations.childLocations' but it didn't populate it at all.